# Several contentPage in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms

I just want know how to create several contentPage in Mainpage. I need it to create Hierarchical navigation. My project deserialise a json, my json describe pages with several views. I can get the views and display them; but know I want to display each views in there page. So to do that I got to create my Views in several ContentPage. How I can do that plz.

Comment: Can you please try to explain what do you mean when say '*Hierarchical navigation*' and '*create my Views in several ContentPage*'. The answer for what you're asking seems quite simple as `for(int i = 0; i < json.Pages.Length; i++) { var page = new ContentPage(); /* stuff */ }`...

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza when I said Hierarchical Navigation I was talking about this link (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical/). So to do that I want to create several "ContentPage" (Pages) put my views in it and switch them with a next and previous button..